# Sitecore populating date field with yesterday's date via $date token

Tags: configuration, templates, fieldtype

I have a date field in one of my templates who's default value is `$date`.  When I create an item using that template, the raw value is `20190522Z`, but when I view it not raw I see it as yesterday's date (5/21).  Likewise it puts it into a bucket structure that's consistent with the actual date \2019\05\22.

I thought I had solved a similar issue before by setting my `ServerTimeZone` to `700` (Eastern Daylight Time) in my `SitecoreSettings.config` file, but this didn't seem to fix this particular issue.  Is there something else I need to set for the CMS to display it with the correct friendly date?

Comment: Can you try $now? I suspect it won’t help but is worth a shot.

Comment: Sitecore will store all dates as UTC and adjust them to your selected server timezone when displaying.

Comment: @MarkCassidy, but my timezone is set to my correct one.  Does that mean I have to set any datefield to something like $date + 4 hours worth of miliseconds or something?

Comment: @jrap, actually that did work!

Comment: Interesting. I'm hesitant to add it as an actual answer. "$date: The system date (yyyyMMdd)" vs. "$now: The date and time (yyyyMMddTHHmmss)". I'll do some research first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between `$date` and `$now` is contained within the `Sitecore.Data.ReplaceValues` method:

```
protected virtual string ReplaceValues(string text, Func<string> defaultName, Func<string> defaultId, Func<string> defaultParentName, Func<string> defaultParentId)
{
    if (text.Length == 0 || text.IndexOf('$') < 0)
    return text;
    ReplacerContext context = this.GetContext();
    if (context != null)
    {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in (SafeDictionary<string, string>) context.Values)
        text = text.Replace(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
    }
    text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$name", defaultName, context);
    text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$id", defaultId, context);
    text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$parentid", defaultParentId, context);
    text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$parentname", defaultParentName, context);
    text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$date", (Func<string>) (() => DateUtil.IsoNowDate), context);
    text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$time", (Func<string>) (() => DateUtil.IsoNowTime), context);
    text = this.ReplaceWithDefault(text, "$now", (Func<string>) (() => DateUtil.IsoNow), context);
    return text;
}
```

Note the key differences:

- `$date`

  - nested calls listed below:
  - `DateUtil.IsoNowDate` = `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "Z"`
  - Replacement: **20190522Z**
- `$now`

  - nested calls listed below:
  - `DateUtil.IsoNow` = `DateUtil.ToIsoDate(DateTime.UtcNow)` (DateTime.UtcNow = datetime *object* of UTC time)
  - `datetime.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss") + "Z"`
  - Replacement: **20190522T122352Z**

Which, as the names imply: `$date` is the UTC **"date"** string and `$now` is the UTC **"date + time"** string.

#### Setting time zones in Sitecore

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/settings-supporting-utc-implementation.html

#### Valid time zone values

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/gg154758(v=winembedded.80)

***Edit***

Richard's answer below explains why the inclusion of the timestamp is important when resolving the proper date. Read his answer in addition to mine.

Comment: How would my server not be set correctly?  I've been testing this out on a local instance, so it's going based on my machine's date, no?  TimeZone in config files is set to the same Eastern Standard Time...

Comment: @LeviWallach, I'll remove that piece. I think Richard Seal nailed the true issue.

Answer (score 6):

Based on @jraps research, this is what I believe is happening:

`$date` is taking the current UTC date and storing that in the DB - if you are in UTC-4 and you create the date when the UTC date has crossed over but your local date has not, then the date will appear to be stored incorrectly. This is because when Sitecore displays that date, there is no time information for it to convert back to your local time.

`$now` is working, because it is storing time information with the date, so Sitecore can now convert that date+time back to your timezone configured in Sitecore.

I guess `$date` *could* be considered a buggy way of storing the date, it would be better if it stored it as `20190522T000000Z`, then it could at least be converted back to your configured time zone.

Comment: So I believe that $date is set up as the default value anytime you create a date field in 8.2.  So essentially Sitecore should probably change that to $now.  Any clue how they set it in 9?

Comment: It's odd, this initially fixed the issue (changing it to $now) on both our dev and production servers, but after a new release the production server is showing yesterday's date again.  Timezone is set the same in sitecoresettings.config (700), and $now is specified in both the Standard values as well as the default value field for the date field.  The odd thing is that if you click on the "today" link after an item is created, the date changes to the correct one, it's just the initial value that is showing yesterday's date - but only on our production server, not our dev server...